# How to make text appears alitter above using html and css

Tags: html, css, text

For example `2nd`, I want to make the `nd` appears bit above using `html` and `css`. how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<sup>` (and `<sub>`, for the opposite effect)

2<sup>nd</sup> H<sub>2</sub>O

Answer (score 1):

> `<sub>` tag defines subscript text. Subscript text appears half a
>   character below the baseline. Subscript text can be used for chemical
>   formulas, like H<sub>2</sub>O.
>
> `<sup>` tag defines superscript text. Superscript text appears half a
>   character above the baseline. Superscript text can be used for
>   footnotes, like WWW<sup>[1]</sup>.

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>2 <sup>superscript</sup> text.</p>
<p>2 <sub>subscript</sub> text.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the department of Hilariously Bad Ideas: You could use UTF8 superscript characters!

2ⁿᵈ

Comment: Yeah, seriously. Don't ever do this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  2<span style="vertical-align: super;">nd</span>
```

Using the vertical-align should do the trick.

Comment: There's no need to use CSS if there's a semantic HTML element with the perfect style already in advance.